# How to test 2 Bitmap images in Android studio using Robotium

Tags: android

```
public boolean equals(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2) {
    ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap1.getHeight() * bitmap1.getRowBytes());
    bitmap1.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer1);

    ByteBuffer buffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap2.getHeight() * bitmap2.getRowBytes());
    bitmap2.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer2);

    return Arrays.equals(buffer1.array(), buffer2.array());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitmaps have a built in method: [sameAs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs(android.graphics.Bitmap))

> Given another bitmap, return true if it has the same dimensions, config, and pixel data as this bitmap. If any of those differ, return false. If other is null, return false.